# How to access updated props in recaptcha callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I'm trying to use the reCaptcha integrated in firebase authentication with React and Redux.

```
const Login = props => {

    useEffect(() => {
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('login-button', {
                'size': 'invisible',
                'callback': () => login()
            }
        );
        window.recaptchaVerifier.render()
    }, []);

    function login() {
        console.log(props)
        firebaseLogin(props.email, props.password).then(() => {
                ...
            }
        ).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            ...
        });
    }

    function onChangePassword(event) {
        props.onChangePassword(event.target.value)
    }

    function onChangeEmail(event) {
        props.onChangeEmail(event.target.value)
    }

    return (
        ...
            <form>
                <label>Dirección de Email</label>

                <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="email"
                           className={`form-control ${emailValidation ? "is-invalid" : ""}`}
                           placeholder="nombre@mail.com"
                           onChange={onChangeEmail} value={props.email} tabIndex={1}
                           autoComplete={"username"}
                           required/>
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">
                        {emailValidation}
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div className="form-group">

                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">

                            <label>Contraseña</label>

                        </div>
                        <div className="col-auto">

                            <Link to="/reset-password" className="form-text small text-muted">
                                Olvidé mi contraseña
                            </Link>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="input-group input-group-merge">

                        <input type={showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
                               className={`form-control ${passwordValidation ? "is-invalid" : ""} form-control-appended`}
                               placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña" onChange={onChangePassword}
                               value={props.password} required tabIndex={2}
                               autoComplete={"current-password"}/>

                        <div className="input-group-append">
                      <span className="input-group-text clickable"
                            onClick={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}>
                        <i className="fe fe-eye"/>
                      </span>
                        </div>
                        <div className="invalid-feedback">
                            {passwordValidation}
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary mb-3"
                        id={"login-button"}
                        tabIndex={3}>
                    Acceder
                </button>
            </form>
        ...
    )
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    onChangeEmail: value =>
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_LOGIN_FIELD, key: 'formEmail', value}),
    onChangePassword: value =>
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_LOGIN_FIELD, key: 'password', value}),
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    email: state.authentication.formEmail,
    password: state.authentication.password,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

The problem is that in the login callback the props are outdated and doesn't contain the email and password that are loaded in the redux store, it just contains the props that were available when the useEffect was triggered. (I see that with the console.log(props))

I don't know how can I keep a reference to the updated props. I've tried using the useRef hook and sending it to the login as a parameter, but that didn't work either.

I've also tried using the email and password props as useEffect dependencies, but that triggers the recaptcha generation a lot of times and it's very inefficient.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work as

```
window.login = useCallback(() => {
        console.log(props);
        firebaseLogin(props.email, props.password).then(() => {
             ...
            }
        ).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            ....
            }
    }, [props]);

useEffect(() => {
        window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('login-button', {
                'size': 'invisible',
                'callback': () => window.login(),
            }
        );
        window.recaptchaVerifier.render();
    }, []);
```

There is another problem, but not related to this question

Comment: Think about maybe also adding a return statement to the `useEffect` like: `return window.login = undefined` to clear the window object on unmounting the component or as I mentioned in the comment below, rather bind the function login to the ref of the component instead of window.

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback hook to access the latest state in a performant manner.

```
    const login = useCallback( () => {
        console.log(props)
        firebaseLogin(props.email, props.password).then(() => {
                ...
            }
        ).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            ...
        });
    }, [ props ] ):
```

On the official react documentation it states: "Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of the dependencies has changed." In our case, the login function will update itself everytime `[props]` changes, meaning when we get new props, we get a new login function.

Check out the official [hook documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for more information on how to use which hook.

You can even use `useCallback` for all of your three functions!

```
    const onChangePassword = useCallback( (event) => {
        props.onChangePassword(event.target.value)
    }, [props.onChangePassword]);

    const onChangeEmail = useCallback( (event) => {
        props.onChangeEmail(event.target.value)
    }, [props.onChangeEmail]);
```

The `onChangePassword` and `onChangeEmail` callback functions will update and create new functions everytime your `props.onChangePassword` and `props.onChangeEmail` functions get updated from redux or higher-order-components.

Comment: If I set the useCallback with props as dependency, then I should put "login" as a dependency of the useEffect, which ends up in the same problem, the recaptcha is being called in every input update.

Anyway, while doing that, the props are still having the same info. I think that the event in the login button it's still referencing the old callback, even if I do a window.recaptchaVerifier.clear() before.

Comment: I get your point and your own answer to the question seems to solve the problem, however I would rather try to bind the login function to the ref of the component instead of window.

Comment: Do you know how that binding can be done? considering that the recaptcha verifier is already in window, I'm not sure if other thing might work

Comment: It works with `window` because `window` is a global object that can be accessed from everywhere. `window.login` will be set to the newest function of `login` (see your answer, in the useCallback you update window.login). It would be the same if you access ref.login instead. The only difference would be that you dont use window and rather a better scoped global object. `const ref = useRef(null);`. Ref will be destroyed when your components get unmount.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how you need to apply the useRef hook. Do you mean doing something like const loginRef = useRef(login) and then calling loginRef inside the useEffect?